# Treating a word such as "NA" as 0 in addition

Tags: excel, vba

I have for Excel macro:

```
Sub Add()
Range("I1").Value = Range("A1").Value + Range("B1").Value + Range("G1").Value
End Sub
```

And this `G1` entry contains the word `NA`, which breaks my addition with error:

> Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

I have tried many things, many I have forgotten:

Things like `NA = 0` and amending the `.Value` to other things, I have tried:

```
if Range("G1").Value = ("NA") Then Range("G1).Value = 0 Endif
```

Nothing seems to work and I can't find anything online.

Comment: Try `= Val(Range("A1").value) + Val(Range("B1").value + ...` Val() converts strings to doubles, and the "NA" should be converted to a zero.

Comment: @MattCremeens One further question, I want to put `For i As Integer = 1 To 5`, then my function `Range("Ii").Value = Range("Ai").Value + Range("Bi").Value + Val(Range("Gi").Value)`.

Will it take `i` in the range like that, and why does it give me error on `For i As Integer = 1 To 5`, `syntax error`, I have copied exactly the form they wanted me to use

Comment: I think you need `Range("I" & i)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
= Val(Range("A1").value) + Val(Range("B1").value + ...
```

`Val()` converts strings to doubles, and the "NA" should be converted to a zero.

If you want the row number to be a variable, you need

```
Range("I" & i)
```